tensorflowjs loadLayersModel function throwing ValueError: An InputLayer should be passed either a `batchInputShape` or an `inputShape`
heres my code for generating and training the model https://github.com/JaylenLuc/Terrestrial-based-ML-cloud-classification/blob/main/cloud.ipynb
I specified the input shape in the VGG16 model yet calling await tf.loadLayersModel(modelUrl);  gives me this error : ValueError: An InputLayer should be passed either a `batchInputShape` or an `inputShape`. 
Not sure how to go about this issue. Perhaps its a versioning issue. Heres my model.json : {"format": "layers-model", "generatedBy": "keras v3.6.0", "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v4.21.0", "modelTopology": {"keras_version": "3.6.0", "backend": "tensorflow", "model_config": {"class_name": "Sequential", "config": {"name": "sequential", "trainable": true, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_shape": [null, 150, 150, 3], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "name": "input_layer_1"}}, {"class_name": "Functional", "config": {"name": "vgg16", "trainable": true, "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_shape": [null, 150, 150, 3], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "name": "input_layer"}, "name": "input_layer", "inbound_nodes": []}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block1_conv1", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 64, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block1_conv1", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 150, 150, 3], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["input_layer", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block1_conv2", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 64, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block1_conv2", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 150, 150, 64], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block1_conv1", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "MaxPooling2D", "config": {"name": "block1_pool", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "pool_size": [2, 2], "padding": "valid", "strides": [2, 2], "data_format": "channels_last"}, "name": "block1_pool", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 150, 150, 64], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block1_conv2", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block2_conv1", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 128, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block2_conv1", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 75, 75, 64], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block1_pool", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block2_conv2", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 128, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block2_conv2", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 75, 75, 128], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block2_conv1", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "MaxPooling2D", "config": {"name": "block2_pool", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "pool_size": [2, 2], "padding": "valid", "strides": [2, 2], "data_format": "channels_last"}, "name": "block2_pool", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 75, 75, 128], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block2_conv2", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block3_conv1", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 256, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block3_conv1", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 37, 37, 128], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block2_pool", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block3_conv2", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 256, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block3_conv2", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 37, 37, 256], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block3_conv1", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block3_conv3", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 256, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block3_conv3", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 37, 37, 256], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block3_conv2", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "MaxPooling2D", "config": {"name": "block3_pool", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "pool_size": [2, 2], "padding": "valid", "strides": [2, 2], "data_format": "channels_last"}, "name": "block3_pool", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 37, 37, 256], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block3_conv3", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block4_conv1", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 512, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block4_conv1", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 18, 18, 256], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block3_pool", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block4_conv2", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 512, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block4_conv2", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 18, 18, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block4_conv1", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block4_conv3", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 512, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block4_conv3", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 18, 18, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block4_conv2", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "MaxPooling2D", "config": {"name": "block4_pool", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "pool_size": [2, 2], "padding": "valid", "strides": [2, 2], "data_format": "channels_last"}, "name": "block4_pool", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 18, 18, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block4_conv3", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block5_conv1", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 512, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block5_conv1", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 9, 9, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block4_pool", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block5_conv2", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 512, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block5_conv2", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 9, 9, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block5_conv1", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "block5_conv3", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "filters": 512, "kernel_size": [3, 3], "strides": [1, 1], "padding": "same", "data_format": "channels_last", "dilation_rate": [1, 1], "groups": 1, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "block5_conv3", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 9, 9, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block5_conv2", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}, {"class_name": "MaxPooling2D", "config": {"name": "block5_pool", "trainable": false, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "pool_size": [2, 2], "padding": "valid", "strides": [2, 2], "data_format": "channels_last"}, "name": "block5_pool", "inbound_nodes": [{"args": [{"class_name": "__keras_tensor__", "config": {"shape": [null, 9, 9, 512], "dtype": "float32", "keras_history": ["block5_conv3", 0, 0]}}], "kwargs": {}}]}], "input_layers": [["input_layer", 0, 0]], "output_layers": [["block5_pool", 0, 0]]}}, {"class_name": "Flatten", "config": {"name": "flatten", "trainable": true, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "data_format": "channels_last"}}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense", "trainable": true, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "units": 128, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense_1", "trainable": true, "dtype": {"module": "keras", "class_name": "DTypePolicy", "config": {"name": "float32"}, "registered_name": null}, "units": 11, "activation": "softmax", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}, "registered_name": null}, "bias_initializer": {"module": "keras.initializers", "class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}, "registered_name": null}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}}], "build_input_shape": [null, 150, 150, 3]}}, "training_config": {"loss": "categorical_crossentropy", "loss_weights": null, "metrics": ["accuracy"], "weighted_metrics": null, "run_eagerly": false, "steps_per_execution": 1, "jit_compile": false, "optimizer_config": {"class_name": "Adam", "config": {"name": "adam", "learning_rate": 9.999999747378752e-05, "weight_decay": null, "clipnorm": null, "global_clipnorm": null, "clipvalue": null, "use_ema": false, "ema_momentum": 0.99, "ema_overwrite_frequency": null, "loss_scale_factor": null, "gradient_accumulation_steps": null, "beta_1": 0.9, "beta_2": 0.999, "epsilon": 1e-07, "amsgrad": false}}}}, "weightsManifest": [{"paths": ["group1-shard1of16.bin", "group1-shard2of16.bin", "group1-shard3of16.bin", "group1-shard4of16.bin", "group1-shard5of16.bin", "group1-shard6of16.bin", "group1-shard7of16.bin", "group1-shard8of16.bin", "group1-shard9of16.bin", "group1-shard10of16.bin", "group1-shard11of16.bin", "group1-shard12of16.bin", "group1-shard13of16.bin", "group1-shard14of16.bin", "group1-shard15of16.bin", "group1-shard16of16.bin"], "weights": [{"name": "dense/kernel", "shape": [8192, 128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense/bias", "shape": [128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_1/kernel", "shape": [128, 11], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_1/bias", "shape": [11], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block1_conv1/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 3, 64], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block1_conv1/bias", "shape": [64], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block1_conv2/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 64, 64], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block1_conv2/bias", "shape": [64], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block2_conv1/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 64, 128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block2_conv1/bias", "shape": [128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block2_conv2/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 128, 128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block2_conv2/bias", "shape": [128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block3_conv1/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 128, 256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block3_conv1/bias", "shape": [256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block3_conv2/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 256, 256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block3_conv2/bias", "shape": [256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block3_conv3/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 256, 256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block3_conv3/bias", "shape": [256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block4_conv1/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 256, 512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block4_conv1/bias", "shape": [512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block4_conv2/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 512, 512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block4_conv2/bias", "shape": [512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block4_conv3/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 512, 512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block4_conv3/bias", "shape": [512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block5_conv1/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 512, 512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block5_conv1/bias", "shape": [512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block5_conv2/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 512, 512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block5_conv2/bias", "shape": [512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block5_conv3/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 512, 512], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "block5_conv3/bias", "shape": [512], "dtype": "float32"}]}]} 
